# Angular2 ng-xi18n: Does not work

Tags: angular, internationalization

I tried many solution tips for using ng-xi18n.

the steps I have done was to uninstall/remove node_modules and installed angular-cli again with npm install --save @angular/cli. and with the last step npm install to get the dependencies.

But everytime I execute npm run i18n I get an error.

package.json:

```
{
    ...
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n --i18nFormat=xmb",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
     ...
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

ng --version:

@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4
node: 7.7.3

My error:

Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported .. resolving symbol AppModule in ode_modules/@angular/cli/blueprints/ng/files/**path**/app/app.module.ts

I hope someone experienced the same problem and can help me.

Thx.

Answer (score 3):

use `ng extract-i18n` instead

```
"extract-i18n": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
    "options": {
    "browserTarget": "angular-i18n:build"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but I had a similar error and needed to point ng-xi18n to my tsconfig.json file. In my case I needed to run:

`./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n -p src/tsconfig.json`

You might need to change your package.json file

```
{
    ...
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n --i18nFormat=xmb -p path/to/tsconfig.json",
    ...
},
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#other-options